# ssh configuration for easier connection to a server

Tags: ssh

I want to set up my ssh config to ssh into a server with one command.

Currently I have to execute these 3 lines on my terminal to ssh into my build server.

```
$ ssh-add
$ ssh -A -t ftp1.foo.net
$ ssh -A -t build02-foo
```

I am on mac and other 2 servers are ubuntu.

What do I have to set up to be able to ssh into `build2-foo` with one ssh command like

```
$ ssh build02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>[The same as on the SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40093976/2196426)</sup>

Create `~/.ssh/config` with

```
Host build02
  Hostname build02-foo
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p ftp1.foo.net
```

and then you can connect just using

```
ssh build02
```

Comment: it works. But the command should be `ssh build02-foo`.

Comment: now it should work also with the `ssh build02`

Comment: space is needed after Hostname :D

Comment: I see now you know how does it work.